# How to restrict indexed_search to show only results of subtree (pages and there subpages) typo3 8 LTS

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

- Search Page Domain 1 should not list results of Domain 2 and Domain 3
- Search Page Domain 2 should only list results of Domain 2
- Search Page Domain 3 should only list results of Domain 3

`- - Domain 1 (uid:1)
- - Lvl1 Page Domain 1 (uid:2)
- - - Lvl2 Page 1 Domain 1 (uid:3)
- - Lvl1 Page Domain 1 (uid:4)
- - Lvl1 Page Domain 1 (uid:5)
- - Search Page Domain 1
- - Microsites (uid:5)
- - - Domain 2 (uid:6)
- - - - Unterseite 1 Domain 2 (uid:7)
- - - - Unterseite 2 Domain 2 (uid:8)
- - - - Unterseite 3 Domain 2 (uid:9)
- - - - Search Page Domain 2
- - - Domain 3 (uid:10)
- - - - Unterseite 1 Domain 3 (uid:11)
- - - - Unterseite 2 Domain 3 (uid:12)
- - - - Unterseite 3 Domain 3 (uid:13)
- - - - Search Page Domain 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TS Setup for Pages:

#### UID:1

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.sections = rl1_2, 4, 5
```

Declaration:

```
rlx_y = Level x, Page y

4,5 = PageUid 4, PageUid 5
```

#### Search results:

> Search Page Domain 1: Shows Content of PageUid's: 2,3,4,5

#### UID:6 (Domain 2 or Subpage)

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.sections = rl1_6
```

#### Search results:

> Search Page Domain 2: Shows Content of PageUid's: 7,8,9

#### UID:10 (Domain 3 or Subpage)

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.sections = rl1_10
```

#### Search results:

> Search Page Domain 3: Shows Content of PageUid's: 11,12,13